# How to dynamically JsonIgnore according to user authorize?

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api

I use Metadata and JsonIgnore to remove special field from being serializing.

```js
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<user> Get()
    {
        using (var mydb = new ModelContainer())
        {
            return mydb.userSet.ToList();
        }
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(user_Metadata))]  
public partial class user
{  
    private class user_Metadata  
    {  
        [JsonIgnore]  
        public virtual password { get; set; }  

        public virtual adminFile { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

How can I dynamic control which field should be serialized or not. For some thing like

```js
public partial class user
{  
    private class user_Metadata  
    {  
        [JsonIgnore]  
        public virtual password { get; set; }  
        [Roles == admin?JsonIgnore:JsonNotIgnore] //some thing like this
        public virtual adminFile { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Conditional property serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

Comment: @JamesNK,Thanks,"Conditional" is the key word what I should search for.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonIgnore` is a property which can't be set dynamically. But you can try something similar like this.

```
public partial class user
{  
    private class user_Metadata  
    {  
        [JsonIgnore]  
        public virtual password { get; set; }  

        //[Roes == admin?JsonIgnore:JsonNotIgnore] //something like this
        public virtual adminFile 
        { 
            get
            {
               if(Roes == admin)
                   return NULL;
               else
                   return adminFile;
            }
            set
            {
               if(Roes == admin)
                   value = NULL;
               else
                   value = adminFile;
            } 
        }  

    }  
}
```

By this way, You can save the default value instead of saving the actual value for a property.

Comment: thank you, this can get things to work.But I'd like to the way in json.net like James said